# How to load content from many posts on a page, only if needed

Tags: ajax, rest-api

I have a page with a list of links to a custom post type (using `wp_query` and `the_permalink()`)

When a link is clicked, some custom fields from that post should appear in a lightbox.

I can load the custom fields from all those posts, and hide them, only displaying if link is triggered. But this seems unnecessary. These posts have images and I don't want to load them unless they're needed.

Wondering what strategy I can use to only load the content from the post if the link is clicked. Is this a job for WP REST API? AJAX? I've used both before but I'm not an expert on determining when usage is appropriate.

Any suggestions for an elegant solution would be appreciated!

Comment: ajax will load them on the fly.

Comment: AJAX is appropriate in this situation.

Comment: Thank you, I implemented ajax here and it's doing exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LazyLoading too, just put the URL for the image in a `data-src` attribute in the element `<img/>`, then on click your anchor, copy the data there to the `src` attribute.

Maybe your lightbox plugin offers an event or config option to put your handler, using jQuery I'd use something like this:

```
$('a.load-lightbox').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $('.lightbox img').each(function(img) {
    var src = img.data('src')
    img.src = src
  })
})
```

Comment: I ended up getting ajax to work since I saw that answer first but, out of curiousity - would there be any advantages to using LazyLoad instead of ajax here?

Comment: Well. Not a huge advantage if the only change you take into account is that with Ajax is one more request (the Ajax request itself), as the images should be loaded anyway on the lightbox showing.However, I'd argue that if you have the markup already loaded then change with JS just one attribute, versus loading via Json posts data to insert into the Dom later, the former is more easy to understand and maintain as almost all the view is in one place rather than sprawled across two or more modules. But that is assuming too much and your Ajax powered view enhancer could be reused in other cases.